# Copy or reference in constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

What is optimal in that code?

```
class C
{
public:
    C(const std::string& str): str_(str) {}
private:
    std::string str_;
}
```

Or

```
class C
{
public:
    C(std::string str): str_(str) {}
private:
    std::string str_;
}
```

Am I right that in the second code I have two copying and I have one in the first code? So first is better?

But sometimes I'd like to create C class like:

```
C c(std::string());
```

And I have a warning (GCC) but code is ok in that case...

Comment: It's better to indicate immutability. (But since this is a constructor, it's pretty obvious anyways.)

Comment: I think variant 2 if you change `str_(str)` to `str_(std::move(str))` also give one copy in the worst case, and 0 copies if you move std::string inside `C` object, and do not use it anymore. Plus you no need to create two constructors one for copy another for move, so variant 2 in `c++11` is better

Comment: just provide two constructors, for copying (`C(const std::string&)`) and moving (`C(std::string &&)`). Thus, compiler will chose constructor depending on the context, considering that you shouldn't move from lvalue (as it will corrupt it) and there is no need in copying from rvalue. Same applies for `operator=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think variant 2 is better in `c++11` days, because of:

```
#include <iostream>

#define HI do { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; } while (false)

class String {
public:
    String() { HI; }
    ~String() { HI; }
    String(const String &) { HI; }
    String(String &&) { HI; }
    String& operator=(const String &) { HI; return *this; }
    String& operator=(String &&) { HI; return *this; }
};

#if 1
class C
{
public:
    C(const String &str): str_(str) {}
private:
    String str_;
};
#else
class C
{
public:
    C(String str): str_(std::move(str)) {}
private:
    String str_;
};
#endif

int main()
{
    C c{String()};
    std::cout << "2\n";
    String str;
    C c2{str};
    std::cout << "3\n";
    C c3{std::move(str)};
}
```

if you enable variant 1 you get: copy + copy + copy,

and in variant 2 you get: move + copy + move + two moves.

Comment: none of your `class C` implementations contains `const String&` constructor. Which will cause one copy without additional moves

Comment: fix one more thing: "if you enable variant 1 you get: copy + copy + copy," -> "you get one copy"

Comment: @AndreiR. No, the first variant of code print `String::String(const String &)` `String::String(const String &)` `String::String(const String &)` so it is 3 copy

Comment: seems only now I've got what you mean. Anyway, providing both `const String &` and `String &&` constructors privides most optimized output (move+copy+move)

Comment: For short strings, copy and move are the same ; so 3 copies will beat a copy + 4 moves

Comment: @M.M if look at libstdc++(gcc) `union { _CharT           _M_local_buf[_S_local_capacity + 1]; size_type        _M_allocated_capacity; };` where `_S_local_capacity` == `15`, so `move` ~ `copy` for string length < `8` on 64bit arch, but `copy` variant may contains more branches, so it require accurate benchmarks

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply have a default parameter value in the constructor

```
class C
{
public:
    C(const std::string& str = ""): str_(str) {}
                          // ^^^^
private:
    std::string str_;
};
```

and write

```
C c;
```

instead of

```
C c(std::string());
```

## ?

---

Note that the

```
C(const std::string& str = "")
```

is redundant anyway when declaring a

```
C() = default;
```

constructor.

---

> Am I right that in the second code I have two copying and I have one in the first code?

Since `std::string` supports the move constructor `std::string(std::string&& s)` you usually don't need to worry about that for this case. The compiler will optimize that as necessary.

Comment: There's also `C c("");` if OP wants it to be explicit.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ OK, you're right. But when I try to initialize `c` like this: `C c("some string");` I have the same problem (warning).

Comment: @peter55555 Unnecessary copying is unlikely since `std::string` already supports `std::move()`.

Comment: I suppose that variant two + unnamed object force compiler to use move instead of copy

Answer (score 1):

`C c(std::string());` is a function declaration. Your warning probably relates to this.

Your two code samples admit the same syntax for creating an object. You could avoid the function declaration problem by using either of these:

```
C c = std::string();
C d{ std::string() };
C e("");
```

and/or , as others have suggested, making a default argument.

---

Regarding whether 1 or 2 is better: 2 should be changed to `str_(std::move(str))` . Otherwise `str_(str)` makes an unnecessary copy.

Theoretically, option 2 would be faster for initializing from an rvalue containing a long string, although you probably won't notice any difference.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases (when the initializing string have been already created and used), the first variant will be better (because of the missing std::move in the second one). But now, in C++11 days, the best solution of course is to cover all possible situations:

```
C() = default;
C(const std::string & str): str_{str} {}
C(std::string && str): str_{std::move(str)} {}
C & operator= (const std::string & str) { str_ = str; }
C & operator= (std::string && str): { str = std::move(str); }
```

Or in case you know what are you doing and you don't need the data in the initializing string anymore, you can explicitly move its content:

```
C(std::string & str): str_{std::move(str)} {}
```